# I read some comic books and I dunno what the meaning of some dialogues, please help me understand it

Tags: translation, meaning, phrase-meaning

1. 자르는 이렇게 고통스럽게 이겨냈던 거야.
2. 양판소 주인공이라 독에 강하긴 무슨.원작소설에서 세자르는 몇 번이고 독에 당했지만, 먼치킨이라 다 이겨냈다는 설명뿐이었다.
3. 너는 대외적으로 황후의 사람이니까 저들이 너를 공격하지는 않을 거야, 이대로 도망간 신관을 따라가서 계획을 전부 알고 있었다고 해.

Comment: where is this from? please provide a link for more context if possible

Answer (score 1):

1. 자르(maybe name) overcame (omitted. Maybe some kind of hard thing) that painfully.

And before second one, here are newly-coined word '양판소'. It is shorthand of '양산형 판타지 소설', means 'Mass-produced fantasy novel'. And '먼치킨' is Munchkin, but in Korea it means something like 'OP character'.

So...

2. It is not like 'strong at poison because (he/she) is hero of mass-produced fantasy novel'. At original novel, 세자르(name) poisoned many time, but setting of the novel is that he overcame it because he is OP.

What word I have to choose to translate 신관? It's something like priest... If you know story of starcraft II, Artanis is 신관 in Korean, and Hierarch in English. So I'll choose word 'hierarch'.

3. They won't attack you because you are man of empress externally. Now follow hierarch who ran away and tell him you have known all the plan.

Note that maybe my translation is incorrect/unnatural.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand that 'Munchkin' thing 